# What are the naming conventions of functions that return boolean?

Tags: c++, coding-style, naming-conventions

I'm not a native English speaker, so I got confused by the naming convention of functions that return boolean.

I have known the following function names are conventional:

```
bool is_valid();
bool is_sorted();
bool is_empty();
bool has_children();
bool can_draw();
```

However, I wonder whether another function names, which begin with verbs other than "is, are, can, has, etc.", are also conventional as follows:

```
bool TryToCloseWindow();    // check to see if the user tries to close the window
bool IntendToCloseWindow(); // as above
bool FileExists();          // check to see if the file exists
```

If you are a native English speaker and programmer, do you think the three function names are conventional?

Comment: There are no fixed naming convention for languages derived from C (like for example C++ and Java). It's is very much up to the individual, or the organization. Different people/organizations have different naming styles.

Comment: I want to know whether the last three looks natural.

Comment: The WIN32 API have several functions named similar to the last three. But if it's your own code you're working on, then it's completely up to you how you want to name and format identifiers. Pick a style that you feel comfortable with, you can even change style between projects. Just keep the style coherent in a single project.

Comment: My real question is: Whether the last three looks natural from a native English speaker.

Comment: If you're interested in what verbs have actually been used in source code for boolean functions and properties, take a look at http://source-code-wordle.de

Comment: I think it depend on context. if the function is part of class, then definitely go with the the Java convention to start bool with is , for e.g, Window aWindow(); if( aWindow.isClosing()); File aFile(); if(File.isExisting());  Otherwise, star with a noun: if(windowIsClosing); if(fileExists); avoid mentioning the user , except for a user class; userwise you would get strange booleans as if (userIsAskingForAfile())

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer to your title question: Different. There are tons of different conventions, perhaps even more conventions than programmers. Some conventions want to have an "is" at the start of every bool returning function's name, others don't. And don't bother questioning/arguing about underscores, CamelCase, lowerCamelCase etc. As long as you stick to the one you picked they are all equally readable.

I think what *is* important is that the function names express what they are doing. Functions returning bools often appear in context of conditionals or loops. So I think its best to put your intended name in such a context and see if it sounds right. e.g. `if (fileExists()) { /* ... */ }` sounds good. `tryToCloseWindow()` sounds like "hey, compiler/program, close that window please". Your comment gives a hint thats not what you want. Maybe use 'userIsClosingWindow()' or something like that. "intend" is not a verb I would use for function names. To intend sth. means you want to do sth., you have it in mind, you are thinking about it, but there is no real action. So if *you* intend to close a window, just do it, or leave it. No need to tell the compiler "hey, I intend to close that window, in a few lines maybe I will actually DO it...". And you have no means to determine if the user intends to close a window. Unless he plugged his Microsoft Mindreader Device into an USB port and you have access to the API, send me a link please, thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the names like `isValid()` it's more meaningful.

It will return the value `true` or `false` so for `if(isValid()) ...`, anybody can understand the concept easily.

Usually not all organisations follow the same naming conventions. It depends from company to company, developer to developer.

Comment: I just want to know whether the last three are conventional.

Comment: if you use like this

bool IsTryToCloseWindow();   
bool IsIntendToCloseWindow();
bool IsFileExists();  

then its more conventional.

Comment: these names are not grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0):

in general this should be the naming convention like the one below start with lowercase.

```
bool tryToCloseWindow();    // check to see if the user try to close the window
bool intendToCloseWindow(); // as above
bool fileExists();          // check to see if the file exists
```

Comment: I find it a bad practice (even though I used this along the way) to name function tryToCloseWindow or intendToCloseWindow as they sound more like commands. I believe that bool variables and functions should be read as questions. isWindowClosed() would be my go to.